# bookshelf js – how to query records by matching criteria on associated records?

Tags: node.js, associations, bookshelf.js

Let's say I have a bookshelf one to many relation Person => Cars, where

Pseudocode

```
# Person

hasMany: cars
id
name

# Car
belongsTo: person
id
make
```

Now I'd like to find all persons who own a 'Rover'.

What I'd was naively hoping for was something like this, which is obviously not working:

```
Person.query({ where: { cars: { make: 'Rover' } } } )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is no really elegant solution. I solved my problem finally, by using joins.

Which looks like this:

```
Person.query((qb) => {
  qb.join('cars', 'cars.person_id', 'person.id');
  // no that the cars are joined,
  // they are available for querying
  qb.where({'cars.make': 'Rover'});
})
.then((result) => {
  // do stuff
})
.catch((err) => {
  // always catch errors
  console.error(err);
});
```

It gets a little more complicated, when you want to query against the counterpart of a of many-to-many relation with pivot/intermediate table but maybe this helps to get started.

Comment: Yeah, it's currently not possible to get a set of models based on a condition of another related model: [#1707](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/issues/1707).

Comment: This can produce various side-effects but this is a simple solution to your problem. This is completely valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `withRelated` option to fetch a related model. Try this,

```
Person.forge()
  .fetchAll({
      withRelated: [{
       cars: function(qb) {
          qb.where({make: 'Rover'})
       }
    }]
  })
  .then(function(persons) {
     //do something
  });
```

More from the docs [here](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-belongsTo)

Comment: I prematurely accepted this answer, while in fact it did not solve my original problem. The query on the related table actually only works on the related items, but not on the main items, which in this case means on the persons.

Comment: `withRelated` option does not remove `Person` objects if the `cars` WHERE does not match. This is not a correct solution.